# check header file of iconv.h

Tags: makefile, autoconf

I am using FreeBSD and have installed `iconv` package form port collection.I wrote

`AC_CHECK_HEADER([iconv.h], ,[AC_MSG_ERROR([can not find iconv.h])])`
`AC_CHECK_LIB([iconv], [iconv_open], ,[AC_MSG_ERROR([can not find iconv_open])])`

in the configure.ac.But when I run ./configure, it gave me the following message

`checking iconv.h usability... no`

`checking iconv.h presence... no`

`checking for iconv.h... no`

`configure: error: can not find iconv.h`

I am sure there is `iconv.h`, `libiconv.la`, `libiconv.so` in the directory of `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib`.So how should I write the correct statement to check the header file and library.Thanks advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the paths `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib` are not searched by default by the compiler. You can do it be modifying the `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` variables in your configure.ac script:

```
CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -I/usr/local/include"
LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -L/usr/local/lib"
```

Add those two lines before you check for the header and library.

Possibly you might have to set `CPPFLAGS` (for the pre-processor) and `CXXFLAGS` (if you are building C++ code) as well, to add the include path.

**Edit:** To set these flags in `configure.ac` is, as noted by William Pursell, not really recommended. Instead you set the these as environment variables when invoking the generated `configure` script:

```
$ CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib ./configure
```

Comment: -I flags belong in `CPPFLAGS` rather than `CFLAGS`

Comment: But the assignment absolutely does not belong in configure.ac.  The user needs to tell the tool chain to look in /usr/local, and the package maintainer should let the user do that.

Comment: @MYMNeo Updated answer with a better way to set these flags.

Answer (score 1):

You should not modify your `configure.ac` in any way.  The user is responsible for telling the tool chain where to look for libraries.  For the user (which is who you are when you run configure), an easy thing to do is to set up a config.site so that the appropriate flags are set.  For example, in your .bashrc: `export CONFIG_SITE=$HOME/CONFIG_SITE`, and then in `$HOME/CONFIG_SITE`, something like:

```
test "$prefix" = NONE && pfx=/usr/local || pfx=$prefix
: ${CPPFLAGS=-I$pfx/include}
: ${LDFLAGS=-L$pfx/lib}
```

This will insert appropriate flags to the compiler and linker to always look in some common locations.

Answer (score 0):

There's always the [AM_ICONV](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/AM_005fICONV.html) automake macro (iconv.m4) which is part of GNU gettext.  You need not use gettext.m4.

Comment: When I added AM_ICONV to configure.ac, autoreconf will report me a message with "required file 'config.rpath' not found", and how to solve it?Thanks!!

Comment: The 'config.rpath' file is part of GNU gettext also. You can copy that file to `AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR` and it should work.